vision transformers: RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x1000 and 768x32)
I am trying to do Regression on the vision transformers model and I cannot replace the last layer of classification with the regression layer
class RegressionViT(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features=224 * 224 * 3, num_classes=1, pretrained=True):
        super(RegressionViT, self).__init__()
        self.vit_b_16 = vit_b_16(pretrained=pretrained)
        # Accessing the actual output feature size from vit_b_16
        self.regressor = nn.Linear(self.vit_b_16.heads[0].in_features, num_classes * batch_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.vit_b_16(x)
        x = self.regressor(x)
        return x


# Model
model = RegressionViT(num_classes=1)
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()  # Use appropriate loss function for regression
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)


I get this error when I try to initialize and run the model
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (32x1000 and 768x32)

The problem is that there is a mismatch between the regression layer and the vit_b_16 model layer, what would be the correct way to solve this issue

that is not an error, that is a piece of code. [mre] required. you know the drill.

If you look into the source code of VisionTransformer, you will notice in this section that self.heads is a sequential layer, not a linear layer. By default, it only contains a single layer head corresponding to the final classification layer. To overwrite this layer, you can do:
heads = self.vit_b_16.heads
heads.head = nn.Linear(heads.head.in_features, num_classes)


Now I solved that issue @Ivan, but there is a issue between the model last layer and the regression head that I am adding, if I resize the last layer that I might loose the data

What do you mean by "resize the last layer"?

That vit_b_16 model is for classification, but instead I want to do regression, so I edited the last layer to include the regression head, but there is a mismatch between the last layer of the model and the regression  head that I am using now

It is not clear what you mean by "regression head", in your example you have a linear layer with num_classes x batch_size logits.

So the vit_b_16 model is trained for classification purposes right. I want to take that model for rotational invariance purposes. I want to remove the last layer that is for classification and replace that into regression layer

So then you would have nn.Linear(heads.head.in_features, 1), correct?

Since I am getting batched outputs from the vit_b_16 model, it will be like nn.Linear(heads.head.in_features, 1*batch_size)

That seems incorrect, the number of parameters does not depend on the batch size. If you have a layer initialized as nn.Linear(in_features, 1), and an input of shape (batch_size, in_features), then the output tensor will be (batch_size, 1). So the
out_features of your linear layer should be 1, not 1*batch_size.
